# I want to fill the missing values in my z matrix with the mean of all the values of the z matrix

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm want to fill missing data in columns with the means of their respective columns and using the code below:

```
#Data Preprocessing
#Importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Importing dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -2].values
z = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

#Dealing with missing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer()
imputer = imputer.fit(x[:,1:3])
imputer = imputer.fit(z[:])
x[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(x[:, 1:3])
z[:] = imputer.transform(z[:])
```

When I try to run this I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-24-f33b6b1880df>", line 15, in <module>
  imputer = imputer.fit(z[:])

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-  packages\sklearn\preprocessing\imputation.py", line 155, in fit
force_all_finite=False)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 441, in check_array  
"if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 1.  3.  4. nan  5.  7.  6.  9.  8. 10.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample
```

The dataset:

```
dataset
Out[37]: 
       Country   Age   Salary  Testing Purchased
   0   France  44.0  72000.0      1.0        No
   1    Spain  27.0  48000.0      3.0       Yes
   2  Germany  30.0  54000.0      4.0        No
   3    Spain  38.0  61000.0      NaN        No
   4  Germany  40.0      NaN      5.0       Yes
   5   France  35.0  58000.0      7.0       Yes
   6    Spain   NaN  52000.0      6.0        No
   7   France  48.0  79000.0      9.0       Yes
   8  Germany  50.0  83000.0      8.0        No
   9   France  37.0  67000.0     10.0       Yes
```

What should I change in my code to fill the missing data in the 'test' column. I tried including the 'test column in x

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you are using a single `Imputer` instance to impute both `x` (2D) and `z` (1D) arrays. You should have created separate imputers for both variables:

```
imputer_x = Imputer()
imputer_z = Imputer()
imputer_x.fit(x[:,1:3])
imputer_z.fit(z[:])
x[:, 1:3] = imputer_x.transform(x[:, 1:3])
z[:] = imputer_z.transform(z[:])
```